# Google Maps Loading Async Issues

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to get Google Maps API v3 to work on my site and I'm running into 2 problems.

1. I'm using [yepnope](http://yepnopejs.com/) to load the API script asynchronously, and I get a "Load denied by X-Frame-Options" error in my console. It says http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=init_google_maps&ver=3.0 does not permit cross-origin framing. This is odd to me because I'm not loading anything in a frame of any kind. Note that the map still loads, but the error in the console concerns me.
2. The map controls aren't displaying correctly. I don't think that this is related to the first issue because I get this even when I load the API the traditional way (synchronously), but it might be related in some way.

[image]

I'm not sure if it matters, but I'm running this on my "localhost" testing server. Any ideas on what could be causing these issues?

**Update:**
As discussed below, the X-Frame issue only occurs when I load the API via yepnope. I can't understand why using yepnope to inject a script tag causes the error and using a simpler js function doesn't though. My main concern, however, is the display of the map. I tested the map on a more stripped down page on my local server, and it displayed correctly. So, my current assumption is that I have a style (or script?) declared somewhere on the page that's interfering with Google maps.

**Update 2:**
Ok, the display issue if finally sorted out. I went through my main stylesheet and commented out portions until I had found the culprit. In order to make my images responsive in my fluid layout, I had declared `img { max-width: 100%; }`. Apparently, Google Maps don't like this. Once I overrode that style for the map container, everything displayed normally. The X-Frame issue still confounds me however.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first problem, if you want to load the Maps API asynchronously, I would suggest using the technique described in the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=no#Loading_the_Maps_API) directly (a simple dynamically inserted `<script>` element) instead of yepnope. It should work fine that way.

On the second problem, running on `localhost` is no problem; that's a normal way to test a Maps API page. (I assume you mean using a local web server and loading your page in the browser from a `localhost://` URL, not a `file://` URL.)

Some symptoms like this can be caused by the map container element not being properly sized when the map is first created. In particular, trying to use `height:100%` can be problematic. But it's hard to guess without seeing a running example. Can you post the code to a web page somewhere? Maybe even in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It's true that when I use the sample code from the documentation, I don't get a X-Frame error. But, I can't wrap my mind around why. I use yepnope for all of my script loading, and I would really prefer to use it if possible. I will try to get some code up in a public place and let you know if I can. As far as styling the container. I'll I'm doing is setting a height of 400px and leaving the width auto. So strange.